# ¿Como evitar cerrar mi aplicación C# desde el Administrador de tareas?

Tags: c#

He estado buscando solución para que mi aplicación escrita en `C#` no sea cerrada desde el **Administrador de tareas de windows**, encontré algunas cosillas por ahí pero están en ingles y no las entiendo, así que esperaba que aquí me puedan ayudar.

Tengo una bandera `cerrar`, la cual controla de forma excelente el cierre desde la aplicación con el siguiente codigo:

```
bool cerrar=false;
...
private void FormCompleta_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if(!cerrar)
    {
       e.Cancel = true;
    }    
}
```

Entonces mientras `cerrar` sea falso la aplicación no se cierra, solo se cierra al escribir la contraseña del que esta en sesión y presionar **enter** con el siguiente código:

```
private void textBoxX2_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter))
    {
        if (Datos.Rows[0]["password"].ToString().CompareTo(CValidaciones.Encrypt(this.textBoxX2.Text)) == 0)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Esta Seguro de Cerrar esta ventana?", "Cerrar ventana", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                cerrar = true;
                this.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        ToastNotification.Show(this, "La contraseña no coincide", global::RFID.Properties.Resources.stop_error, 3000, (eToastGlowColor.Red), (eToastPosition.TopRight));
    }
}
```

Todo esto funciona bien, el caso es:

> evitar el cierre desde el ADMINISTRADOR DE TAREAS de windows

Answer (score 1):

esto no es un proceso fácil, y hasta donde tengo entendido puede que sea imposible bloquear completamente que tu aplicación sea cerrada desde el adm de tareas.

básicamente la solución que tienes que hacer es decirle a tu app que debe ser protegida y cuando quieras cerrarla quitarle la protección, esto provocara que el sistema operativo inicie el proceso de apagado en el momento en el que un usuario fuerce el cierre

en si no puedes evitar que se cierre pero cuando la cierren provocará que el sistema se reinicie.

te dejo esta respuesta del stack en ingles

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16968581/how-to-prevent-an-app-from-being-killed-in-task-manager